# How to force black and white output in google benchmark

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I'm using google benchmark in Xcode and it's producing colored output for some reason. Since Xcode doesn't seem to support colored output I'm seeing undesired symbols. I was wondering if it is possible to force black and white output in google benchmark. I prefer answers that use their API but I'm open to other alternatives.

Comment: have you tried following parameter --benchmark_color={auto|true|false}?

Comment: Great! that does the trick. Do you know if there's any way to specify that from CMake? @ArtemyVysotsky

Comment: To apply @Artemy Vysotsky correct suggestion, you could create script that calls benchmark executable with the correct parameter. You could even have that file committed to your version control and then have cmake copy that file to your build directory. See the cmake command  [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html)

Comment: well, If anyone writes it in the answer I'll just accept it and assign the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color output of Google Benchmark is mentioned in their Readme: https://github.com/google/benchmark#output-formats

> Output Formats
>
> The library supports multiple output formats. Use the
>   `--benchmark_format=<console|json|csv>` flag to set the format type. console is the default format.
>
> The Console format is intended to be a human readable format. By
>   default the format generates color output. Context is output on stderr
>   and the tabular data on stdout.

There is also option to save non-colored copy of output to file with `--benchmark_out=file --benchmark_out_format=console` (default is json)

> The library supports writing the output of the benchmark to a file
>   specified by `--benchmark_out=<filename>`. The format of the output can
>   be specified using `--benchmark_out_format={json|console|csv}`.
>   Specifying --benchmark_out does not suppress the console output.

And in implementation they have the flag to disable console coloring:

https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/a271c36af93c7a3b19dfeb2aefa9ca77a58e52e4/src/benchmark.cc#L87

```
 DEFINE_string(benchmark_color, "auto",
          "Whether to use colors in the output.  Valid values: "
          "'true'/'yes'/1, 'false'/'no'/0, and 'auto'. 'auto' means to use "
          "colors if the output is being sent to a terminal and the TERM "
          "environment variable is set to a terminal type that supports "
          "colors.");
```

So, you can [use `--benchmark_color=false` as suggested by Artemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117069/how-to-force-black-and-white-output-in-google-benchmark#comment79473316_46117069) (using wrapper shell script), or try to pass console output with "useless cat pattern":

```
 ./program | cat
```

It should set [stdout to fail `isatty()` check](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/09b93ccc6a9aed84c269b6f5b8130c878e518ebb/src/colorprint.cc#L184) in auto-color default mode (this trick works to disable color grep).

Or change your TERM env variable with `export TERM=ansi` to indicate that you have green-and-black CRT monitor:
https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/09b93ccc6a9aed84c269b6f5b8130c878e518ebb/src/colorprint.cc#L167

```
  //                 ... This list of
  // supported TERM values is copied from Google Test:
  // <https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L2925>.
  const char* const SUPPORTED_TERM_VALUES[] = {
      "xterm",         "xterm-color",     "xterm-256color",
      "screen",        "screen-256color", "tmux",
      "tmux-256color", "rxvt-unicode",    "rxvt-unicode-256color",
      "linux",         "cygwin",
};
```

But with `|cat` and `export TERM=ansi` gbench continues to generate color. **It must be a bug (!!!)** near `GetOutputOptions`, making IsColorTerminal() logic a noop in case of "auto", so "auto" mode is not really auto it is always enable:

```
ConsoleReporter::OutputOptions GetOutputOptions(bool force_no_color) {
  int output_opts = ConsoleReporter::OO_Defaults;
  if ((FLAGS_benchmark_color == "auto" && IsColorTerminal()) ||
      IsTruthyFlagValue(FLAGS_benchmark_color)) {
    output_opts |= ConsoleReporter::OO_Color;
  } else {
    output_opts &= ~ConsoleReporter::OO_Color;
}
```

The IsTruthyFlagValue considers default value "auto" as true, and always enables color output, even when terminal does not support it!

```
bool IsTruthyFlagValue(const std::string& value) {
  if (value.empty()) return true;
  char ch = value[0];
  return isalnum(ch) &&
         !(ch == '0' || ch == 'f' || ch == 'F' || ch == 'n' || ch == 'N');
}
```

Here is the patch to enable auto mode (will work with `|cat` and `TERM=ansi ./program` and probably with some IDEs which correctly sets TERM), fell free to do pull request:

```
--- a/src/benchmark.cc
+++ b/src/benchmark.cc
@@ -555,7 +555,8 @@ bool IsZero(double n) {
 ConsoleReporter::OutputOptions GetOutputOptions(bool force_no_color) {
   int output_opts = ConsoleReporter::OO_Defaults;
   if ((FLAGS_benchmark_color == "auto" && IsColorTerminal()) ||
-      IsTruthyFlagValue(FLAGS_benchmark_color)) {
+      (FLAGS_benchmark_color != "auto" &&
+       IsTruthyFlagValue(FLAGS_benchmark_color))) {
     output_opts |= ConsoleReporter::OO_Color;
   } else {
     output_opts &= ~ConsoleReporter::OO_Color;
```

Comment: bug introduced in 1.2.0 version by 0de985ae9d4ea1582125a5414a99ca90c368ca10 https://github.com/google/benchmark/commit/0de985ae9d4ea1582125a5414a99ca90c368ca10 commit (biojppm  Joao Paulo Magalhaes committed on Mar 2 2017) - old logic was to use IsTruthyFlagValue only when color option is not auto. https://github.com/google/benchmark/commit/0de985ae9d4ea1582125a5414a99ca90c368ca10#diff-5cd986c2288650e5c5d336b92dcfafd1L549